# Is it appropriate in the MVC pattern to use the builder pattern in the View part

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, builder

```
public class AddFormConcreteBuilder extends FormBuilder
{
    private JDateChooser dateChooser;
    private InsertProducer producer;
    private DataObject dataObject;
    private JTextField AssetName;   
    private JTextField Financial;   
    private JTextField Location;
    private JComboBox Custodian;
    private JComboBox Type;
    private JComboBox RetentionPeriod;
    private JComboBox MaintenanceSched;
    private JComboBox Confidentiality;
    private JComboBox Integrity;
    private JComboBox Availability;
    private JComboBox Classification;
    private JButton btnConfirm;
    private JButton btnBack; 
    private ArrayList<DataSet> insertList = new ArrayList<DataSet>();
    private int AssetID = generateNewAssetID();


    private PanelManager PanelHolder;
    /**
     * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
     */
    @Override
    public void buildComponents()
    {
        PanelHolder = new PanelManager();
        ComboBoxManager comboModelCreator= new ComboBoxManager();
        myForm.setSize(1200,644);
        myForm.setLayout(null);

        Custodian = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.CustodianData());
        Custodian.setBounds(135, 130, 144, 20);
        myForm.add(Custodian);

        Type = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.TypeData());
        Type.setBounds(135, 163, 144, 20);
        myForm.add(Type);

        RetentionPeriod = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.RetentionPeriodData());
        RetentionPeriod.setBounds(161, 230, 118, 20);
        myForm.add(RetentionPeriod);

        MaintenanceSched = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.MaintenanceSchedData());
        MaintenanceSched.setBounds(161, 274, 118, 20);
        myForm.add(MaintenanceSched);

        Confidentiality = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.ConfidentialityData());
        Confidentiality.setBounds(161, 354, 118, 20);
        myForm.add(Confidentiality);

        Integrity = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.IntegrityData());
        Integrity.setBounds(161, 393, 118, 20);
        myForm.add(Integrity);

        Availability = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.AvailabilityData());
        Availability.setBounds(161, 429, 118, 20);
        myForm.add(Availability);

        Classification = new JComboBox(comboModelCreator.ClassificationData());
        Classification.setBounds(161, 467, 118, 20);
        myForm.add(Classification);

        JLabel lblAssetName = new JLabel("Asset Name : ");
        lblAssetName.setBounds(24, 92, 101, 24);
        myForm.add(lblAssetName);

        AssetName = new JTextField();       
        AssetName.setBounds(135, 94, 144, 20);      
        myForm.add(AssetName);
        AssetName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblCustodian = new JLabel("Custodian :");
        lblCustodian.setBounds(24, 128, 75, 24);
        myForm.add(lblCustodian);

        JLabel lblType = new JLabel("Type :");
        lblType.setBounds(24, 166, 60, 14);
        myForm.add(lblType);

        JLabel DateAcquired = new JLabel("Date Acquired :");
        DateAcquired.setBounds(24, 191, 101, 24);
        myForm.add(DateAcquired);

        JLabel lblRetentionPeriod = new JLabel("Retention Period :");
        lblRetentionPeriod.setBounds(24, 236, 118, 14);
        myForm.add(lblRetentionPeriod);

        JLabel MaintenanceSchedlbl = new JLabel("Maintenance Schedule : ");
        MaintenanceSchedlbl.setBounds(24, 275, 153, 24);
        myForm.add(MaintenanceSchedlbl);

        JLabel lblFinancial = new JLabel("Financial : ");
        lblFinancial.setBounds(24, 310, 90, 24);
        myForm.add(lblFinancial);

        Financial = new JTextField();
        Financial.setBounds(135, 309, 144, 20);     
        myForm.add(Financial);
        Financial.setColumns(10);

        JLabel Confidential = new JLabel("Confidentiality: ");
        Confidential.setBounds(24, 355, 127, 24);
        myForm.add(Confidential);

        JLabel lblIntegrity = new JLabel("Integrity :");
        lblIntegrity.setBounds(24, 399, 75, 14);
        myForm.add(lblIntegrity);

        JLabel lblAvailability = new JLabel("Availability : ");
        lblAvailability.setBounds(22, 435, 103, 14);
        myForm.add(lblAvailability);

        JLabel lblClassification = new JLabel("Classification :");
        lblClassification.setBounds(24, 473, 118, 14);
        myForm.add(lblClassification);

        JLabel lblStorageLocation = new JLabel("Storage Location :");
        lblStorageLocation.setBounds(24, 507, 127, 14);
        myForm.add(lblStorageLocation);

        Location = new JTextField();                
        Location.setBounds(161, 501, 118, 20);

        myForm.add(Location);
        Location.setColumns(10);

        btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");        
        btnConfirm.setBounds(403, 524, 179, 49);
        btnConfirm.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 22));
        myForm.add(btnConfirm);

        btnBack = new JButton("Back");              
        btnBack.setBounds(629, 524, 180, 49);
        btnBack.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 22));
        myForm.add(btnBack);

        dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        dateChooser.setBounds(143, 191, 136, 20);
        myForm.add(dateChooser);
    }
```

This is the sample concrete builder pattern that will be used as the View. Is it really appropriate since it is the builder but not the view? I'm still a newbie with regards to design patterns. sorry for that. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that a Builder is a perfectly good kind of thing to use in the role of a view.

It's not really a good question to be asking yourself though. Design patterns exist to help you find solutions to specific problems and to discuss them with others using a common vocabulary. If the code follows good OOP principles such as coherence, consistency, etc., and is easy to understand and maintain, then it doesn't really matter whether your code strictly meets the definition of some particular named design pattern or other.